how do i get name of color from hexCode in flutter?
I'm trying to retrieve the color name from a hex code. I'm using a method where I capture image from a camera and extract the hex code from those images successfully. However, I'm struggling to accurately determine the corresponding color name.
I use this code get color name and hexcode:
Future<void> _getImageAndPickColor() async {

    final pickedFile =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      
      final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
      final image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));

      final pixelColor = image!.getPixel(image.width ~/ 2, image.height ~/ 2);

      
        final red = pixelColor.r;
        final green = pixelColor.g;
        final blue = pixelColor.b;

        _pickedColor =
            Color.fromRGBO(red.toInt(), green.toInt(), blue.toInt(), 1);

        _hexCode = _pickedColor.value.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0').substring(2);

        colorName(_hexCode);
       
      
          _searching.text = _colorName;
          print('colorName $_colorName');
          print('hexcode $_hexCode');
          searchFilter(_hexCode);

        //showMyDialogForCamera(context);
    } 
  }


hex colors are not bound to any name unless you have a static reference which holds the color names and color values. what you couls do is define a set of colors and try to "guess" the color by rgb values

Like the commenter already mentioned, you can try to find the closest color from a given set. You can treat the RGB space as a 3-dimensional space, and use a simple square root of the squared sum to get the eucledian distance like:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

double distance(Color a, Color b) {
  return sqrt(
    pow(a.red - b.red, 2) + 
    pow(a.green - b.green, 2) + 
    pow(a.blue - b.blue, 2)
  );
}

And using this function, you can find the closest color by comparing each color in your set to this color
const colors = [Colors.red, Colors.pink, Colors.lightGreen, Colors.orange];

const myColor = Color(0xffaa00ee);

var minDistance = double.maxFinite;
Color? closestColor = colors.first;

for (final color in colors) {
  final currentDistance = distance(color, myColor);
  if (currentDistance  < minDistance) {
    // it is closer! Use this one for now
    closestColor = color;
    minDistance = currentDistance;
  }
}
print('Closest is $closestColor');


I think HSV space would be better for this than RGB space.

Yep, thinking about it I agree with you @RandalSchwartz. The original hex representation had me focus on RGB immediately. Fortunately, converting the colors seems simple enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204484/15469537
